# Grails file uploader plugin template render issue

Tags: javascript, grails

I am trying to use this plugin my my grails application: [Ajax Uploader Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/ajax-uploader)

It requires me to put this in my head tag:

```
<head>
   <r:require module="fileuploader" />
   <r:layoutResources />
</head>
```

my head tag actually looks like this:

```
<head>
<Title>Solutions, Inc.</Title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'custMainPage.css')}" type="text/css">   
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<g:javascript src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js" />
<g:javascript src="jquery.tablesorter.js" />
<g:javascript src="jquery.tools.min.js" />
<g:javascript src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js" />
<r:require module="fileuploader" />

<script>
    $("document").ready(function() {

        $(".custoption").click( function() {
            $(".custoption").css("color", "black");
            $(this).css("color", "red");
            $('#AdminConsole p').css("font-size", "48px");
            $("#AdminConsole p").text("Choose Batch");
            $("#pleaseChoose").hide();
        }); 

        $("#chseupdt").click( function() {
            $('#AdminConsole p').css("font-size", "48px");
            $("#AdminConsole p").text("Choose Batch");
            $("#pleaseChoose").hide();
        }); 
    });
 </script>
 <r:layoutResources/>
```

and I keep getting this error:

```
| Error 2014-06-19 18:47:15,806 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR [/FatcaOne_0].[default]  -      Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/FatcaOne_0] threw exception
Message: It looks like you are missing some calls to the r:layoutResources tag. After rendering     your page the following have not been rendered: [defer]
    Line | Method
->> 1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

I get this error when I try to render a template into my gsp. The template basically looks like this:

Some inline CSS,
Some inline JS,
Some HTML

does my layoutResources tag need to be in my template? If so where in the template does it belong since the template doesn't have a head and/or body tag.

---

**Update: It seems I only get this error when I try to put the `<uploader>` tag in a template and then try to render it. If it is not in a template and instead on a gsp itself, it appears just fine. Anyone care to take a stab at why this form won't appear on a template? The error appears right when the template is rendered.**

---

**Another Update thought: So it seems that the uploader plugin gsp tag is failing to render when it goes through Grails' templating mechanism but render's fine when it has to go through the layout mechanism. Meaning, it renders fine on a whole gsp but it won't render when the GSP is already there and you try to bring it in on a template. That is when I get the error I have shown below. So what is different between the layout and templating mechanisms that could be causing this?**

Comment: Refer how [layoutResources](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/ref/Tags/layoutResources.html) work. It has to be used in the end of the body tag as well. Also refer how [layouts](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/03/grails-goodness-applying-layouts-in.html) are added.

Comment: @dmahapatro Ok I will do that. I actually tried it in my body tag as well as in my template. Same error. Thanks for the links I will read it to see if I get any other idea.

Comment: I also tried it by playing with its disposition attribute. No success yet.